# Disadvantages of setting Tomcat's RECYCLE_FACADES = true?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

The [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/systemprops.html) states that the default value for org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES = false.  However, the [Security Considerations web page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/security-howto.html#System_Properties) says:

> Setting org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES system property
>   to true will cause a new facade object to be created for each request.
>   This reduces the chances of a bug in an application exposing data from
>   one request to another.

Because the default value is the less safe value, I wonder why.  I assume that part of it has to do with performance, but I haven't seen much discussion on RECYCLE_FACADES.  What are the drawbacks of setting it to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary disadvantage of setting `org.apache.catalina.connector.RECYCLE_FACADES=true` is **performance**. Tomcat re-uses as many objects as possible across requests in order to reduce *GC churn* (that is, repeatedly creating and discarding many objects). There is no performance difference due to the *use* of these objects -- only the discarding and re-creating cycle that reduces performance.

The default setting is not "unsafe" *per se*, but applications with bugs can cause Tomcat to appear to do very strange things. So if applications aren't breaking any rules, then the higher-performance configuration should be preferred.

If you don't trust the applications that are running on your Tomcat instance, you should definitely enable `RECYCLE FACADES`.

Comment: A note several years after the original answer: one could argue that short-lived request objects can live and die in Eden/NewSpace/[whatever its called when you read this comment] very happily and that GC isn't hampered by dead objects, but by live objects. What is being reduced, here, is the *allocation* of heap memory. It's true that GC pauses are proportional to the number of live objects in the heap, but *reducing allocation* can reduce the frequency with which the GC has to run, which is always advantageous.